# Cutting rectangular pieces of a rectangular paper and minimizing the wastage.

Tags: algorithm

A rectangular piece of paper is given of W*H(widht * height). One is supposed to cut  rectangular pieces out of it. The list (having 'k' elements) of size of the pieces is given. The size of the pieces is given by w*h. All the numbers are integers.

The cut must go from one end to the other.

There could be any number of pieces  of the listed sizes(including no piece).

The aim is to use as much paper as possible, i.e minimize wastage.

Can anyone suggest me how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is your typical knapsack problem.  i will spare you the details here but you can get more info and ideas on how to approach it here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem